TinyMCE call Link modal
I have some code to convert a link to a button in TinyMCE, this is the part that processes the user selection. At the moment, if a link isn't selected I simply tell the user they need to select a link. It occurs to me it would be more sophisticated if it called the routine that produces the TinyMCE link modal.
How do I do this?
editor.addCommand('addBtn', function() {
        // find out what we selected
        var selectedContent = editor.selection.getContent({
            'format': 'html'
        });
        // need a selection of length > 0
        if ( selectedContent.length === 0 ) {
            alert( 'Please select some text' );
            return;
        }
        // Look for the link
        var selectedLink = jQuery(selectedContent).attr('href');
        if ( typeof(selectedLink) === "undefined" ) {
            alert( 'Please select a link' );
            [TIMYMCE LINK MODAL HERE] 
            return;
        }

        var selectedText = jQuery(selectedContent).text();

        


The mceLink command opens a link dialog for the current selection:
editor.execCommand('mceLink');

It requires the link plugin:
tinymce.init({
  plugins: 'link'
});

A predefined list of links can be specified in link_list:
tinymce.init({
  link_list: [
    { title: 'Title1', value: '#link1' },
    { title: 'Title2', value: 'link/2' }
  ]
});

